# Colorbox working on second click

Tags: c#, jquery, repeater, colorbox

I'm creating dynamic links through repeater and binding the links from server at **OnPreRender**. But the color box only works after first click. I'm using live to bind the dynamic links.

Code is follows:

```
    protected virtual void BindJQuery()
    {
        string jquery = string.Empty;
        jquery = StoreLocation() + "Scripts/jui/jquery-1.8.0.min.js";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(jquery, jquery);
    }

    protected virtual void BindColorBox()
    {
        string jquery = null;
        jquery = StoreLocation() + "Scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(jquery, jquery);
    }

    protected void BindColorBoxC()
    {
        StringBuilder urlScript = new StringBuilder();
        urlScript.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        urlScript.AppendLine("$('.iframeC').live('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).colorbox({width: '660px', height: '416px', iframe: true}); });");
        urlScript.AppendLine("</script>");
        string js = urlScript.ToString();
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "colorboxC", js);
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        BindJQuery()
        BindColorBox();
        BindColorBoxC();
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

**Edit:**

I had replaced the following line:

```
urlScript.AppendLine("$('.iframeC').live('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).colorbox({width: '660px', height: '416px', iframe: true}); });");
```

With:

```
urlScript.AppendLine("$(document).on('click','.iframeC',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).colorbox({width: '660px', height: '416px', iframe: true}); });");
```

But the result is same. It's still not working on first click. And there is no overlay because it's a fresh page load.

Any kind of help is Appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
urlScript.AppendLine("$('.iframeC').live('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).colorbox({width: '660px', height: '416px', iframe: true}); });");
```

to this

```
urlScript.AppendLine("$('.iframeC').on('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).colorbox({width: '660px', height: '416px', iframe: true}); });");
```

`.live()` is deprecated in jquery so better to use `.on()` in place of that.And make sure that you are closing your colorbox in a proper manner.Sometimes if the colorbox is not closed properly , the overlay will disabled you to click on any other element.And on first click the overlay will be disapper and on second click you can go with click.SO makesure your colorbox while closing

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
urlScript.AppendLine("$('.iframeC').live('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).colorbox({width: '660px', height: '416px', iframe: true}); });");
```

By and then try

```
urlScript.AppendLine("$(document).on('click','.iframeC',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).colorbox({width: '660px', height: '416px', iframe: true}); });");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with this line.

```
urlScript.AppendLine(" $(document).delegate('.iframeC', 'click', function (e) {
                $.colorbox({ iframe: true, width: '660px', height: '416px', href: this.href });
                return false;
            });");
```